# how to retrieve the selected row cell value if it is visible property is false in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to retrieve the selected row cell value if it is visible property is false in gridview ?

Comment: how would it be selected if it's visibility is false?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense because if the row is not visible how are you (the user) going to select it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't set Visible to false. Set Style Display to none

Create a css class like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

And set ItemStyle-CssClass, HeaderStyle-CssClass  to hidden . Then, you should be able to read cell text. If you set Visible to false, you will not be able to retrieve the value as the column won't be databound.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1937-how-to-get-hidden-column-value-gridview.aspx